# How to access cms plugins created inside a Placeholder field

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a Placeholder field in a model, defined like this:

```
content = PlaceholderField(product_section_content_slotname)
```

I created a custom view to export this model instances in a Json file, how can I access the many CMSPlugins created inside this content Placeholder field?

Is there a way to access them directly from the model?